# How to implement NSLog in Codename One native interface?

Tags: ios, codenameone

I read and followed the instructions from the Codename One manual's Advanced topics [section on Native Interfaces](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_native_interfaces). I want to pass Strings to my interface so that I can log events in the iOS version of my app, but am not able to see my logs.

Here is my code:

```
InterfaceLogger interfaceLogger = NativeLookup.create(InterfaceLogger.class);
if (interfaceLogger != null && interfaceLogger.isSupported()) {
            interfaceLogger.logThis("hello!");
}
```

Here is my iOS implementation code in the `native` folder:

**.h file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface org_myapp_app_cn1_InterfaceLoggerImpl : NSObject {
}

-(void)logThis:(NSString*)param;
-(BOOL)isSupported;
@end
```

**

**.m file:**

```
#import "org_myapp_app_cn1_InterfaceLoggerImpl.h"

@implementation org_myapp_app_cn1_InterfaceLoggerImpl

-(void)logThis:(NSString*)param{
    NSLog(@"%@", param);
}

-(BOOL)isSupported{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need that as `Log.p()` already invokes `NSLog` or `printf` internally. Apple changed the way logging is echoed in recent versions and made a bit of a mess of tracking everything when targeting multiple device generations so `NSLog` just doesn't work everywhere anymore.

The code you did is just fine though, the reason you can't see the `NSLog` output is because of Apple. You can see the internal issue we have for this  here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2166

Comment: Thanks. Would using `printf` create the log? When I use `Log.p()`, I don't see it iTools as I'm working on a Windows machine, so I made this interface so I could see the logs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with itools so I can't help much there. Our Log.p() should echo to NSLog or printf. I see from a recent commit that Steve changed this back to use NSLog by default which might solve your issue with Log.p(). This change should be up on the build servers this Friday

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait to see what happens with the new changes.